# Firefox issue: Encountered with this Exception { message: "", result: 3253927937, name: "NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED"..}

Tags: firefox, ngredux

Encountered with this Exception

`{ message: "",
 result: 3253927937,
 name: "NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED"..
}`

We are using Angular 1.5v.

when using `ngReduxProvider.createStoreWith()` when logging second time only in Firefox but not in Chrome. When we are initializing state with default then this issue is not seen but previously stored values are lost.Please find the attached screenshot

[Issue with Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHDMR.png)